# SharePoint 2007 views, how to use additonal filters?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath forms library in my SP site, and need to create view with more than 8(I guess thats the limit) filters. It would help If I can somehow implement a `Field Contains 'ABC' OR 'DEF' OR 'GHI'` kind of functionality, by just using one filter column in the view.
Or if some way I can just use as many filters as I want instead of the limit!

Answer (score 0):

For more filters you need to use data view webpart.

Please add the web part using sharepoint designer and configure it accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: is there anyway to implement a Field Contains 'ABC' OR 'DEF' OR 'GHI'
by just using 1 column of filter?